# lifecycle out of order, related to 'back key detected but Activity not ending

Tags: android

This is related to the question at:

[back key detected but Activity not ending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365349/back-key-detected-but-activity-not-ending)

Basically, I have to hit BACK twice to exit my Activity (I'm calling it C)  There is a status method called sessionActive().

If sessionActive() is FLASE and BACK is pressed Activity C should end.

I have included a call to finish() in the onKeyDown()/onBackPressed()

I have traced thru the onCreate(), onResume() etc methods and don't understand the sequence I see.  The below snippets from logcat show lifecycle methods seemingly happening out of order:

```
C.onCreate() 
C.onStart() 
C.onResume() 
C.onKeyDown() sessionActive()==false, keyCode = BACK              
                      This is the 1st BACK press that should get us out but doesn't

C.finish() sessionActive is FALSE                                
                      Shouldn't this execute onStop()?

C.onPause() sessionActive is FALSE      <- Why are these running?
C.onRestart() sessionActive is FALSE       
C.onStart() sessionActive is FALSE      
C.onResume() sessionActive is FALSE

C.onStop() sessionActive is FALSE       <- These makes sense.
C.onDestroy() sessionActive is FALSE

C.onPause() sessionActive is FALSE      <- Why didn't the previous onDestroy() stop us?

C.onResume() sessionActive is FALSE     <- Confusing!!!

C.onKeyDown() sessionActive is FALSE, keyCode = BACK
                    This is 2nd BACK press that causes Activity C to exit.

C.finish() sessionActive is FALSE
C.onPause() sessionActive is FALSE      <- Why is there is no onRestart here?

C.onStop() sessionActive is FALSE       <- This is the sequence I expect.
C.onDestroy() sessionActive is FALSE
```

Is this normal?  If it is, I do not understand why the lifecycle is executing differently.

Can it be related to how Activity C is started:

```
    Intent startActivity = new Intent();
    startActivity.setClass(this,C.class);
    startActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(startActivity);
```

Can it be related to the application being defined as android:launchMode="singleTask" ??

Are there any requirements about how the Activity launching C should be defined/started?  How about the Activity launching the Activity launching C?